# How to solve this equation numerically?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Two Gaussian functions: f1,f2 of the form `f1 = a1*Exp[-t^2/s1^2]`.  Total area, Atot of (f1+f2) is known.  Height of each peak (a1 and a2) is known (experimental data).  I don't want to experimentally determine FWHM, although it could be done.  Integration gives:

```
Atot=Sqrt[2 π] (a1 s1 Erf[1/(Sqrt[2] s1)] + a2 s2 Erf[1/(Sqrt[2] s2)])
```

By plotting the function for Atot, I know this has four solutions for variables {s1,s2} for a given Atot, a1, and a2.  However, constraint is that s1 and s2 both > 0, which yields one unique solution.  (i.e. Atot = 1.1001, a1 = 0.382, a2 = 0.384)

How to solve in Mathematica?

Comment: Two unknowns require two equations. You need another one involving `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: In addition to what was noted by @J.M., it looks like the total area is not accounting for overlap. It is not obvious from the problem statement whether that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the solution is not unique!

This code gives a range of values where both $s_1$ and $s_2$ are positive (there are other ranges also).

```
Atot[a1_, a2_][s1_, s2_] := 
  Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (a1 s1 Erf[1/(Sqrt[2] s1)] + a2 s2 Erf[1/(Sqrt[2] s2)]);
Manipulate[
  With[
    {s1 = q}, FindRoot[Atot[.382, .384][s1, s2] - 1.01, {s2, 1}]
  ], {q, .255, .735}
]
```

For example  ($s_1 = .255$ and $s_2 = 7.70763$) or ($s_1=0.5$ and $s_2=0.660332$), etc.

[image]